# Percentage cover using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I need to calculate the percentage of coral cover (polygon layer) in a 1 km radius around each record of fish (point layer). There’re about 4000 points (blue squares in the image).

I am new to QGIS.

[image]

Comment: Can I suggest that you add the QGIS tag and take off coverage (an Arcinfo-Workstation composite datatype), I thought you were doing this in ArcINFO workstation. In reality this is an easy task: buffer your fish by 1k, find the area, clip/intersect with coral and then find the percentage of each buffer polygon (by area) that intersects coral. There's a few tutorials around for QGIS geoprocessing that will help: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the information and the suggestion regarding the tags. That webpage surely helps.